# Regular expression range that must not start at zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a regular expression where only values from 1 thru 99 are allowed.

Valid values:

```
1
01
2
02
3
03
...
19
20
21
...
98
99
```

Everything else must throw an error like:

```
00
0
-1
1.0
1.
100
```

I currently have this:

```
^[1-9]([0-9]+$)
```

This is not working. It only accepts values from 10 and above.

Comment: Would a simple `> 0` and `<100` not work? (with int parse)

Comment: Yes it will work but I am busy with form validation and binding the validation to the form. There is a `RegularExpression` attribute that I am using. It is more convenient to use the validation controls already provided in `.NET`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
^(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

Answer (score 2):

`^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`

first part covers 1 to 9 and the 0x

second part is for everything between 10 and 99

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work : `^(([0-9][1-9])|([1-9][0-9])|[1-9])$`

Comment: yea that I am thinking right now sorry i will edit it

Comment: You can't 'think' on SO :) I also had it like that. It doesn't work for `01`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])$/mg
```

Demo here [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nI6nW5/1)

It uses the `|` operator which is equivalent to `OR`.

So basically this Regex is saying:

> Is the number between 1 and 9?
>
> OR
>
> Is the first number between 1 and 9, and the second number between 0
>   and 9?
>
> OR
>
> Does the number begin with a 0 and end with a number between 1 and 9?

The flags on the end `/mg` just make it check each line for the demo, you may want to change or remove these.

**Edit:** For whatever reason I didn't see Kuba's answer. His is actually cleaner, but works in roughly the same way as this one should you have wanted an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`/^(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$/gm`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/oW6aJ4/2).